# Annotation @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class) is not initializing mocks in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito, junit-runner

I am trying to write a test class in Kotlin with org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.4.31 in my build.gradle.

In my test class, mocks are not getting initialized via the '@RunWith' annotation i.e. :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
```

e.g. I am using

```
@InjectMocks lateinit var bookService: BookServiceImpl
```

For above mocks to get initialized I have to use 'MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)' (otherwise I get exception)
e.g.

```
@InjectMocks lateinit var bookService: BookServiceImpl

@Test
fun testStudentGenerationEvent(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    val student = MyTestUtil.getStudentDTO()
    bookService.prepareStudentGenerationEvent(customerData, "test-student-topic")
}
```

can anyone suggest why above behavior is happening? Why @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class) is not initializing the mock (
I get exception

```
    lateinit property bookService has not been initialized kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property bookService has not been initialized
```

) and only     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) is able to initialize.

Comment: Are you using JUnit 4 or JUnit 5? If you're using JUnit 5, you should use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)`.

Comment: amazing! this works and the mock got initialised. 
But still I didn’t quite get the reasoning behind the above behaviour. To answer your question though I am using Junit4 ( as I already mentioned the dependency org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.4.31).
So I dunno why this worked ?!

Comment: If using `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)` works, then you're using JUnit 5, not JUnit 4.

Comment: Okay, how can we check the version. As per the dependency it says 1.4.31 (so I suppose it is junit4) please correct or add if wrong/missing anything. Thank you.

Comment: That dependency of kotlin-test-junit does not necessarily mean you're using JUnit 4 or 5. It depends on what `@Test` annotation you imported.

Comment: Okay. But anyways what is the reason it gets intialized with @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class) and not with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class). Any idea?

Comment: Mark Rotteveel just told you. Your @Test annotation is either from org.junit.jupiter annotation or an org.junit. The former being junit 5 and the latter junit 4.

Comment: Because `@RunWith` is JUnit 4, and `@ExtendWith` is its more powerful replacement in JUnit 5.